# Does a temporary Ability Score increase change my spells-per-day?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can I use Adamant Entertainment's version of the Warlock School Ability to boost spell casting ability to gain extra spells per day?

> **Transmutation**
>
> **Augment (Sp):** As a standard action, you can touch a creature and grant
> it either a **+2 enhancement bonus to a single ability score** of your
> choice or a +1 bonus to natural armor that stacks with any natural
> armor the creature might possess. **At 10th level, the enhancement bonus
> to one ability score increases to +4.** The natural armor bonus
> increases by +1 for every five wizard levels you possess, to a maximum
> of +5 at 20th level. This augmentation lasts a number of rounds equal
> to 1/2 your wizard level (minimum 1 round). You can use this ability **a
> number of times per day equal to 3 + your Intelligence modifier.**

Secondly, wouldn't raising your spell casting ability (Int [or Cha via archetype]) also increase the number of times per day you can use this School ability? While base use is 3 times a day with an additional number of uses = user spell ability, does the increase in that ability for effect and duration reset the extra number of times it can be used in a day thus giving the user an almost infinite number of ability uses?

Comment: You seem to be confusing a spell-like ability with a spell. Are you asking if increasing your Spell Casting Ability score with this ability will increase your bonus spells per day, or increase your uses of this ability? And what do either of those questions have to do with gestalt or multi-class-ness?

Comment: Maybe...but none the less does this increase in Ability score net the user extra spells per day for having a high score? And this ability is used X times a day, does it mean you extra spells as well?

Answer (score 4):

Changes to Ability Scores are treated as [temporary](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores/#Ability_Score_Bonuses) (and don't affect certain things) until they have been in place for 24 hours.

> Ability score increases with a duration of 1 day or less give only temporary bonuses.
>
> Ability bonuses with a duration greater than 1 day actually increase the relevant ability score after 24 hours. Modify all skills and statistics related to that ability. This might cause you to gain skill points, hit points, and other bonuses. These bonuses should be noted separately in case they are removed.

So unless you can increase the duration of this ability to 24 hours somehow, it won't give you bonus spells or additional uses of spell-like abilities.

Also, the bonus Transmutation gives is an enhancement typed bonus. The [rules of bonuses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary/) state:

> The important aspect of bonus types is that two bonuses of the same type don’t generally stack. With the exception of dodge bonuses, most circumstance bonuses, and racial bonuses, only the better bonus of a given type works. Bonuses without a type always stack, unless they are from the same source.

If you use Transmutation to increase the same Ability twice you only get the benefits once. Transmutation also doesn't stack with things like the [headband of vast intelligence](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/headband-of-vast-intelligence/)

Comment: Ok so it's a temporary stat buff it will have a limited effect mostly statistical (HP, Skills, Spell DC,  Ability dependent things etc) so this shouldn't work with Alchemist Bombs and the sort right?

Comment: I believe that Alchemist Bombs will do more damage if you Augment your Intelligence, but that is an extrapolation of other rules. Ex: increasing Str increases melee damage, so I would assume increasing Int increases bomb damage, since they are both Ability dependent things. I do not think it would increase the number of bombs you have per day though.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9rbg) clarifying this, it's worth reading it.

Comment: About the number of bombs per day.  Temp Ability mod prob might work since all the Alchemist needs is ingredients similar to spell components they throw together. "Drawing the components of, creating, and throwing a bomb requires a standard action" Since Augment last in rounds equal to the users level a single use of Augment, they should be able to "jerry rig" a few more bombs a day per use.